# Socket to Socket communication, with Server only acting as at middleman

Tags: java, sockets, serversocket, data-transfer

There are countless answers on this site about how to communicate between a ServerSocket and a Socket, but I have not found any which explain how you could simply have a ServerSocket act as a middleman when communicating between two Sockets.

I want a ServerSocket which, when a Socket connects to it, receives one Integer and then uses that Integer as an "address". When a Socket (S1) connected to the ServerSocket sends an Integer, the Server is to check if it has another Socket (S2) related to that Integer. If it does, it should simply have any data sent by S1 forwarded to S2. This should continue until S2 sends a "stop" value to the Server.

Essentially; rather than Server-Client communication, I want Client-Client communication (with a Server helping the Clients connect to each other). Anyone have any ideas for how to do this?

EDIT: It seems like what I called "Client-Client" is properly called "Client-Server-Client"

Comment: Your second paragraph describes a "client-server-client" setup, where two clients connect to a server and server forwards messages between them, while your last paragraph asks for "client-client" connection. Which one is it you're asking about?

Comment: Also, "client" and "server" only have well defined meaning withing the client-server architecture, so you'll probably have to define what "client-client" really means. Or maybe you're talking about client and server within TCP protocol, not at application level? In that case "client-client" is impossible.

Comment: What I meant was, I suppose, a client-server-client setup

Comment: This is simply called a *proxy*, and there are many types of proxies and many examples to choose from, include many examples here on stackoverflow, for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30829110/java-making-proxy-socket-multithreaded) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6047815/using-sockets-in-java-with-a-proxy).

Comment: @JamesKPolk That does look promising. I'll try it out